Compactness of $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$ in topology consisting of $\tau_\text{Eucl} \cup \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$
I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology generated by $\tau_\text{Eucl} \cup \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$ is locally compact. To show that the topological space is locally compact in the irrational points, I want to show that any interval of the form $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$ is compact. That is certainly the case for $\tau_\text{Eucl}$, and my sense is that any opens in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$ do not contribute to an open cover of $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$, but I'm not sure how to formalize this. Any help would be appreciated.

That is not true. Pick a rational $q\in (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ and let $q_n=q-\frac{1}{n}$. Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $q_n\in (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ for any $n\geq m$. Then $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$ has an open cover consisting of the following sets:
$$[x-\epsilon, q_m)$$
$$\{q_n\}\text{ for all }n\geq m$$
$$(q_n, q_{n+1})\text{ for all }n\geq m$$
$$\{q\}$$
$$(q,x+\epsilon]$$
I've deliberately separated some of those sets, to clearly see which arise from the Euclidean piece, and which from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$ (singletons). These are all open and cover entire $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$. And since they are pairwise disjoint this cover does not have a finite subcover. It doesn't have a subcover at all.
